# Formula only sees string as string and not as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, formula

I have a little code that takes a user input and encrypts it. It's not a hash formula but its just a simple enigma code. the code *simplified* is:

```
def Hash (string):
    for x in range(0, len(string)):
        if x == 0:
            HashC = str(ord(string[x:x+1]))
        else:
            HashC = HashC+str(ord(string[x:x+1]))
            print(HashC)
    U = HashC

U = input("What do you want to hash? ")
Hash(U)
print(U)
```

The output with the print so show me whats going on in the conversion.

```
>    What do you want to hash? Test
>    84101
>    84101115
>    84101115116
>    Test
```

What I want it to Output

```
>    What do you want to hash? Test
>    84101
>    84101115
>    84101115116
>    84101115116
```

Because I want the code to change the string into the "*encrypted*" code.

Comment: What is wrong? You haven't said what you're expecting to see that differs from what you got. I suspect you've got an issue expecting C++ style pass-by-reference semantics (`str` are immutable, and no change in `Hash` will change the variable `U` outside of `Hash`), but that's just a guess at what you think is going wrong.

Comment: `return HashC` instead of `U = HashC` and `U = Hash(U)` instead of `Hash(U)`. As pointed above, strings in Python are immutable.

Comment: @vendaTrout thank you do you mind creating the answer? Or do you just want me to delete this question?

Comment: Also, you can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16865251/767632) answer.

Comment: @yeputons this doesn't help with my formula returning the coded answer

Comment: Also, the assignment `U = HashC` will create a function-local variable called `U` rather than assigning to the global namespace. To fix that, even though it is a bad idea, add `globals U` to the top of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the variable `U` lies outside the function. When you assign `U = HashC` in the function block, the block assigns it to `U` but as the function block exits, `U` is restored to its value of `input()` in this case Test. This is like **pass by value** in C, only here `U` is visible to the function block without explicitly passing to it. Also, you have to store this value in `U` as strings are immutable, although as such you did not make a change to `string`

Therefore, you should do something like :

```
def Hash (string):
    for x in range(0, len(string)):
    if x == 0:
        HashC = str(ord(string[x:x+1]))
    else:
        HashC = HashC+str(ord(string[x:x+1]))
        print(HashC)
    return HashC

U = input("What do you want to hash? ")
U = Hash(U)
print(U)
```

Comment: Not sure if you were implying this, but the line `U=HashC` in the function actually makes the value of `U` from outside completely invisible within the function. Once you make that assignment, `U` becomes a local variable and no global lookup will be done on it at all. Attempting to reference it in the function before the assignment will cause a `NameError`.

Comment: Nope, function can still see `U`. For instance, just define `a = 1`. `def x(): print(a)`. This will print `1`. Correct me if I have not understood your comment properly.

Comment: `def x(): print(a); a=2` will raise a NameError even if you assign `a=1` globally as you did. Doing `a=2` *anywhere* within the function makes `a` a local variable throughout the entire function

Answer (score 2):

`U` in `Hash` is a local variable, not the global one.

Add `global U` above `U = HashC` may solve the case.

But it is a good practice to *not* modify global variable, as it creates side effects, and it often leads to some kind of bug. So return `HashC` in `Hash` and `U = Hash(U)` instead.